# exception logs not present in file logs

Tags: logging, logback, logstash-file, logstash-logback-encoder

In spring boot project the logback is configured as below..Now the problem is if there is any exception its not present in logged file but its showing in stdout.

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd:HH-mm-ss.SSS"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <file>/var/log/app/backend-business-workflow/${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}_${HOSTNAME}_application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/app/backend-business-workflow/archive/${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}_${HOSTNAME}_application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
<!--            <pattern>"timestamp":"%date","requestId":"%X{x_request_id}","spanId":"%X{x_span_id}","level":"%level","threadId":"[%thread]","class":"[%file:%line]","message":"%msg"%n</pattern>-->
            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampPattern>
            <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
            <includeMdcKeyName>x_request_id</includeMdcKeyName>
            <includeMdcKeyName>x_span_id</includeMdcKeyName>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %X{x_request_id} %X{x_span_id} %level [%thread] [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
            <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<!--    <logger >-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;        <level value="INFO" />&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />-->
<!--    </logger>-->

    <root >
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with logstash-logback-encoder 6.6 and spring boot 2.5.1.

Comment: @LMC in your log file exception are printing with above logstash file?

Comment: Yes,exceptions print with same configuration.